# post http in form not working

Tags: javascript, html, forms

POST http method in my form does not work when I use JavaScript:

```
<form id="user" method="post"action="url"  onsubmit="return false;">
    <span>First Name:</span>
    <input type="text" class="input" id="fname" name="fname" required>
    <span>last Name:</span>
    <input type="text" class="input" id="lname" name="lname" required>
    <input  class="button" type="submit" value="submit" onclick = "checkForm()"> 
</form>
```

However, it does seem to work when I do not use JavaScript:

```
<form id="user" method="post"action="url">
    <span>First Name:</span>
    <input type="text" class="input" id="fname" name="fname" required>
    <span>last Name:</span>
    <input type="text" class="input" id="lname" name="lname" required>
    <input  class="button" type="submit" value="submit"> 
</form>
```

How can I use JavaScript validations in my form and send the form to a given URL?

Comment: You are cancelling the submission with `onsubmit="return false;` of course it will not post to the server.

Comment: on submit should be `onsubmit="checkForm()"` and checkform should send the form after validation `form.submit();`

Comment: @epascarello is right but it seems that `checkForm()` have to send the form. Check if it is working.

Comment: @epascarello yeah its true thnx, i resolved it n posted the answer too

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<form id="user" method="post"action="url"  onsubmit="return checkForm();">
    <!-- blah blah-->
     <input  class="button" type="submit" value="submit">
</form>
```

Thanks for your help; this is working fine now.

Answer (score 0):

It is not submitting to server because `onsubmit="return false;"` tells the browser the validation failed and do not send to server. If `onsubmit` is not specified or returns `true` the data will be submitted to the specified url. The following code should work if the function `checkForm()` returns true when passing validation and returns false while failing validation.

```
<form id="user" method="post" action="url" onsubmit="checkForm()">
    <span>First Name:</span>
    <input type="text" class="input" id="fname" name="fname" required>
    <span>Last Name:</span>
    <input type="text" class="input" id="lname" name="lname" required>
    <input  class="button" type="submit" value="submit"> 
</form>
```